# Update CentOS to Python 2.7

Tags: centos, redhat, python

What is the best way to install Python 2.7 on CentOS? All the tutorials I'm seeing are either using a third party management system or manually installing a separate binary to co-exist with Python 2.4. Why is 2.4 needed, and how can I seamlessly install 2.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up going with Python 2.7 and took the following steps:

1. Download the source
2. Update `gcc` and other build tools.
3. `configure && make && make altinstall`

For Django:

4. Removed `django` from the original 2.4 `site-packages` directory.
5. Reinstalled django using `python2.7 setup.py install`.

[A longer and much more detailed version can be found here.](http://joshuakehn.com/2011/2/4/Upgrading-Python-on-CentOS.html)

Comment: I had to add the following steps : echo /usr/local/lib >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/usrlib.conf && ldconfig

Comment: @yanjost: Where exactly did you have to add that step?

Comment: after step 3, because libpython2.7.so could not be found

Comment: +1 for the blog post link

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.4 is incompatible with Python 2.6. CentOS packages and a lot of core features depend on python.

> how can I seamlessly install 2.6?

For (for x64 change i386 to x86_64):

```
rpm -ivh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/i386/epel-release-1-1.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/i386/ius-release-1.0-6.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
yum clean all
yum install python26
```

Then disable epel and ius (set `enabled=0` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/ius.repo` and `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`)